# Function to plot pairs() variables against common vertical axis variable in the diagonal

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to define a function to produce a scatterplot across the diagonal of a pairs plot. The trick is that I'd like to specify the vertical axis probably in the `panel.splot` function. Ultimately I think the use here is to visualize a time series on the diagonal. For a simple example though I'd like to try this with the iris dataset and use `Species` as the vertical axis variable. The plot below produces a nice looking plot:

```
pairs(iris[,c(1:4)])
```

So now I'd need to define a function for the diagonal panel. Here is my efforts so far:

```
panel.splot <- function(x, yvar,...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 2, usr[3:4]))
  plot(yvar,x, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)))
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get an error message that I'm not sure how to interpret.

```
pairs(iris[,c(1:4)],diag.panel=panel.splot(x=x, yvar="Species"))

Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I haven't been able to find another example of this. Lots of other functions to create different types of plots but nothing that does exactly this.

For clarity, this is the type of plot I am imagining would be produced along the diagonal of the `pairs()` call:

```
plot(iris$Species,iris$Petal.Width)
```

Comment: I haven't used `pairs`, but I once glanced on `GGally::ggpairs`; have a look at the last example ("Custom examples"), where it seems fairly easy to assign whichever plot to whichever coordinate in the grid of subplots. I just tried to put a plot on the diagonal using `custom_car[1,1] <- plot`.

Comment: Inside `panel.splot`, you are attempting to take the `min` and `max` of `yvar` which contains the string `Species`.  I don't think you intended that.  This won't fix your problem but it seems to be an issue.

Comment: what's `x` in `pairs(iris[,c(1:4)],diag.panel=panel.splot(x=x, yvar="Species"))
`

Comment: If I run it without the `x=x`, I get this error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`. @steveb: You are right. Edited the question.

Comment: you're trying to `plot('character string', numeric_vector)`, change to `plot(iris[, 'Species'], x)` and add `new = TRUE` to par, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your example plot, i interpreted this slightly differently (incorrectly) due to *use Species as the vertical axis variable*. Hubert's given the answer but thought it might add something.

Using`pairs()`

```
panel.splot <- function(Y, Adjust=0.2){
                    function(x, y=Y, adjust=Adjust)
                    {
                     usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
                     xs <- range(x)
                     ys <- if(is.factor(y)) c(1, nlevels(y)) else range(y)
                     par(usr = c(xs[1], xs[2], ys[1], ys[2]) + c(-adjust, adjust))
                     points(x, y)
                    }
                 }

pairs(iris[, 1:4], diag.panel=panel.splot(Y=iris$Species))
```

Which produces

[image]

To do the same thing with `ggpairs()` you can also define a user function

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)    

# Define diagonal function
diag_fun <- function(data, mapping, ...){
      ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
      geom_point(...) 
      }

ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4, 
        diag = list(continuous = diag_fun, mapping=aes(y=Species)))
```

Which gives

[image]

---

Update for your comments...

Yes, for the diagonal entries, the variable is passed as the `x` mapping. You can either use `coord_flip()` or reverse the mapping in the function. The function below does this, and adds the variable names using `annotate()` (ps. you should be able to swap out the `_point` geom for say, `_boxplot`

```
diag_fun <- function(data, mapping, xnudge=0.95, ynudge=1, pts=lst(), ...){

    # create range for annotate
    lbl <- as.character(mapping$x)
    xmax <- max(data[, as.character(mapping$x)], na.rm=TRUE)
    ymax <- mean(seq(nlevels(data[,as.character(mapping$y)]))) 

    # reverse mapping so no need for coord_flip() 
    tmp <- mapping$y
    mapping$y <- mapping$x
    mapping$x <- tmp

    ggplot(data=data, mapping=mapping) + 
      do.call(geom_point, pts) +
      annotate("text", x=ynudge*ymax, y=xnudge*xmax, label=lbl, ...)
      }
```

So to use it in `ggpairs` with the defaults

```
ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4,  diag = list(continuous = diag_fun, mapping=aes(y=Species)))
```

And you can use `wrap` to pass further arguments

```
ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4,  
        diag = list(continuous = 
                      wrap(diag_fun, 
                           size=10, col="red", # make changes to the text label
                           pts=list(colour="blue")), # make changes to geom_point
                    mapping=aes(y=Species)))
```

Comment: @user20650 You are right. I intended the question to read Horizontal axes not Vertical axes. My mistake. This appears not be trivial as when I changed the mapping argument in to `mapping=aes(x=Year)`, I get the following error `Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y`. I don't see in the `diag_fun` where I could alter the function. Any ideas here? Following on from this I would like the x-axis labels (horizontal) to be displayed on each diagonal panel. Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: i@bosshek; ill have a wee look tomorrow - so are you wanting points plotted or do you want boxplots? (ps is it enough to add `+ coord_flip()` to `diag_fn` - the names are in the bottom right panel

Comment: @user20650 the `coord_flip()` indeed does work. Still I am interested to understand why `geom_point` appears to require an `y` aesthetic but not an `x` aesthetic. Is the `x` aesthetic supplied by `ggpairs`? Indeed I want points for this application but I'd like to keep it flexible enough to change it.

Comment: @user20650 Also for names comment - the `pairs` example has the variable names directly embedded into the corresponding diagonal plot.  I thought that maybe `showStrips=TRUE` might accomplish this but no. I can imagine doing this via `geom_text` but I can can't wrap my brain around how to specify the `x` and `y` of the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Following rawr recommendations, I managed to get your plot:

```
panel.splot <- function(y)
{
        function(x,yv=y)
        {
                usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
                par(usr = c(0, 2, usr[3:4]), new = TRUE)
                plot(yv,x)
        }
}
pairs(iris[,1:4],diag.panel=panel.splot(iris[,5]))
```

[image]

You'll still have to deal with text size

Comment: thats why I was suggesting something like `plot(iris[, yv], x)` and passing yv directly in the panel function either by default `panel.splot  <- function(x, yv = "Specis")` or anonymously `diag.panel=function(x) panel.splot(x, yv = "Species")`